# how can I trigger click to open a dropdown

Tags: angular

I need a dropdown to open without a manual click. I have tried many things, among those is.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  document.getElementById("mydropdown").click();
},5000)


<select id="mydropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

but it does not work. What I can do?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xinu88?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I looked - there doesn't seem to be any method on HTMLSelectElement to open the dropdown, and as you have found, `.click()` does not open it.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek yes...

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no way in normaly to open select/option from JS,but you can create your custome dropdown if you want like [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp).
your code is correctly call click event and if you add this code below you can see it:

your .html:

```
<select id="mydropdown" (click)="onClick($event)>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

your .ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     let dropdown: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('mydropdown') as 
      HTMLElement;
      setTimeout(() => {
        dropdown.click();
      }, 5000);
  }

  onClick(event) {
    console.log('occured!');
  }
```

Comment: The more standard Angular way to get a reference to a child element is through the @ViewChild annotation.

Comment: yes but in this case, I wanna make the answer highest similarly to the question convention. but thank you for advicing.

Comment: @MostafaSaadatnia is this working? what is this.test(dropdown)?

Comment: @yavg click event raised in this sample but unfortunately, there is no way to emulate real click on the dropdown from javascript/typescript file.